# MySQL5.7 group replication questions?

Tags: mysql

I want to try **mysql5.7.17** group replication. And I followed the steps on [MySQL Group Replication: A Quick Start Guide](http://mysqlhighavailability.com/mysql-group-replication-a-quick-start-guide/)  to configure mysql-group-replication on two host. But only the node which first starts replication can be online, the other one always recovering.

I got the below logging info from mysql server side.
 [image]

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You have some duplicated data on your second member. 
If you have the same data on the first and second member, then the transactions that originated that data must have the same GTIDs.